# Range Facets with SearchPlus and Algolia

Tags: entries, search, plugin-searchplus

Currently using Algolia with SearchPlus on my setup. Unfortunately some data is quite clunky e.g. Prices with 23.93 48.12 etc. What I'm wanting to do is have range pricing/grouping where by I can define 20-50 as a facet and all prices within those ranges appear?

```
<!-- Facet template -->
<script type="text/template" id="facet-template">
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    <div class="product-search-facet-row">
        {{#values}}
        <div class="checkbox toggle-refine {{#isRefined}}facet-refined{{/isRefined}}"  data-facet="{{ facet }}" data-value="{{ name }}">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" {{#isRefined}} checked{{/isRefined}}>
                {{ name }}
            </label>
        </div>
        {{/values}}
    </div>
    <hr/>
</script>
```

Not sure if this is an Alogia side or SearchPlus JS.